# Error 403 403.4 in uploading to Google Docs using Zend

Tags: api, zend-framework, doc

I tried using google docs sample in the Zend Gdata demos and got the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 200, got 403 403.4 SSL required' in
>   F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata\App.php:714 Stack trace: #0
>   F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata.php(219):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://docs.goo...', Array,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL) #1 F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata\App.php(880):
>   Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://docs.goo...', Array) #2
>   F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata\App.php(768):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->get('http://docs.goo...', NULL) #3
>   F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata\App.php(210):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('http://docs.goo...', 'Zend_Gdata_Docs...',
>   NULL) #4 F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata.php(162):
>   Zend_Gdata_App->getFeed('http://docs.goo...', 'Zend_Gdata_Docs...') #5
>   F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata\Docs.php(130):
>   Zend_Gdata->getFeed('http://docs.goo...', 'Zend_Gdata_Docs...') #6
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.11.12\demos\Zend\Gdata\Docs.php(277):
>   Zend_Gdata_Docs->getDocumentListFeed('http://docs.goo...') #7
>   F:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.11.12\demos\Zend\Gdata\Docs.php(752):
>   retrieveWPD in F:\PHP_libs\Zend\Gdata\App.php on line 714

I am using Zend library for the first time and am unable to figure out how Authorization works here. Please help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is fixed in the latest version of the Zend library but I went and updated  this file in my Zend install:
library/Zend/Gdata/Docs.php

The constants around line 62 needed to be updated to change the http to https which now look like this in my install:

```
const DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full';
const DOCUMENTS_FOLDER_FEED_URI = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/folders/private/full';
const DOCUMENTS_CATEGORY_SCHEMA = 'https://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind';
const DOCUMENTS_CATEGORY_TERM = 'https://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder';
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `https` instead of `http` if you want to connect to GoogleDocs, which is stated in the error message you are getting: `Expected response code 200, got 403 403.4 SSL required`. The parts of the message are interpreted like this:

- `Expected response code 200`: the called method expect the http response code to be `200`
- `got 403`: the actual received http code
- `403.4 SSL required`: a short description to the code

Look at [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to get more information.

The examples from the [Zend Framework: Documentation: Using Google Documents List Data API - Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.docs.html) aren't up-to-date and should be like this:

```
$feed = $docs->getDocumentListFeed(
    'https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full/-/document');
```